# program to test SMTP server

Tags: java, testing, smtp

I have a program in Java using subethasmtp(a SMTP server library) to test if I can receive mails from another program correctly. I can get all the information that I want using this program.

Now I need to show all the information in a web page, what is the best way to do it?

I do not want a database to store the data, and I'm not so familiar with the front-end. Is there a way that I can push the information to my web? I want a light solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://sparkjava.com/

It's a simple and lightweight Java web framework for rapid development. You can use it to generate a simple HTML page that display the data you have collected.